# Install Ruby 2.0.0-p247 with rbenv and erro in /tmp/ruby

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to install Ruby 2.0.0-p247 with rbenv and I keep getting the same error no matter what I do. Here's the command and response:

```
➜  ~  rbenv install 2.0.0-p247                                         
Downloading ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz...
-> ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.gz
Installing ruby-2.0.0-p247...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20130823153529.15739
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20130823153529.15739.log

Last 10 log lines:
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:242:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:242:in `install_recursive'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:397:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:758:in `call'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:758:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:755:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:755:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:751:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:751:in `<main>'
make: ** [do-install-all] Erro 1
```

Comment: So... the contents of `/tmp/ruby-build.20130823153529.15739.log` would   probably be of interest to you.

Comment: Do you have enough space on `/tmp` ? Also would recommend to read build log and not only last lines.